# displaying integer value using core data in a label or text view (objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I created an Xcode app which stores user input using the core data framework in this case reviews (detail and rating 0-5).

So basically I have managed to create a view controller which stores the user inputs and then displays it in a table view controller.

Users are able to then choose any existing reviews they want from the table view controller, which then takes them to a new view controller which displays that specific review the user chose.

The problem is that I have managed to display the string value using this code "`[self.detailView setText:[self.managedObject valueForKey:@"detail"]];`" but I cannot get it to display the rating value which is stored as integer(16) in the core data.

.h detail view controller

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "reviewTableViewController.h"
#import "reviewViewController.h"
#import "Reviews.h"

@interface reviewDetailViewController : UIViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate> //adding fetched controller delegate and text field delegate

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *detailView; //holds detail values
@property (nonatomic, strong) Reviews *reviews; //property for holding reviews
@property (strong) NSManagedObject *managedObject; //hold core data property
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ratingView; //holds rating values
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton1;    //buttons for borders

@end
```

.m detail view controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _myButton.layer.borderWidth = .5f;
    _myButton.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor]CGColor];     //adding borders for tet displa using buttons, when screen loads
    _myButton1.layer.borderWidth = .5f;
    _myButton1.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor]CGColor];

    [self.detailView setText:[self.managedObject valueForKey:@"detail"]]; //displaying detail value
    //[self.ratingView setText:[self.managedObject valueForKey:@"rating"]];
    //[self.ratingView setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:managedObject]         forKey:@"rating"];//displaying rating value
     //[self.puzzle setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:timeTaken] forKey:@"bestTime"];



}
```

.m table view controller

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    //  Get a reference to our detail view


//  Pass the managed object context to the destination view controller
 //  [super prepareForSegue:segue sender:sender];
    //  If we are editing a picture we need to pass some stuff, so check the segue title first
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"detailSegue"]) //using segue link name given
        {
          //Get the row we selected to view
            NSManagedObject *managedObjects = [self.reviewsArray objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]]; //choosing the selected cell value
            reviewDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
            destViewController.managedObject = managedObjects; //displaying it in the destination controller



    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the integer into a string.

```
[self.ratingView setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.managedObject valueForKey:@"rating"]]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSNumber *x = managedObject.rating; // rating is NSNumber!
int y       = x.intValue;           // this is how you get an int!

label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", managedObject.rating.intValue];
```